# How to make mediaView appear always at the center of BorderPane in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I need media view at the center of border pane but non of the BorderPane.setMargin or BorderPane.setAlignment are working.[Screenshot of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHoJu.jpg)

```
MediaView mediaView = new MediaView();
Media media = new Media("file:/E:/video.mp4");
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
mediaView.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);
mediaView.fitWidthProperty().bind(video_BorderPane.widthProperty());    

BorderPane.setMargin(mediaView, new Insets(100,100,100,100));
BorderPane.setAlignment(mediaView, Pos.CENTER);

video_BorderPane.getChildren().addAll(mediaView);
```

Comment: It would be best to provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem. Are you sure the `BorderPane` itself is taking up the space you expect?

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: Just noticed you aren't adding the `MediaView` to your `BorderPane` correctly. Don't add to the children list directly, use `video_BorderPane.setCenter(mediaView)` instead.

Comment: @Slaw I've tried it... But that doesn't makes the media view grow or shrink when i move the divider of SplitPane... All i want is to make media view grow or shrink when I move the divider while keeping it at the centre.... The red box around the mediaView represent borderPane... Any solution will be appreciated...